# how can we gray out background when we make setmodal(false) in window in gwt

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.4

In window I am using `setmodal(true)` so mouse events are not working. Hence, I changed to `setmodal(false)` but background is not gray out hence we can able to click the buttons below the dialog box. So kindly advise me how to gray out, after making `setmodal(false)` in GWT

Comment: Modal=true means that the active dialog is the only thing you can interact with. Are you saying that you want modal=false so you *can* interact with the rest of the page, and yet the page grayed out so you *can't* interact with it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `setGlassEnabled(true)` to grey out along with the `setmodal(false)`. Refer [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html#setGlassEnabled%28boolean%29) for details.

Comment: setGlassEnabled(true) is present in Popuppanel class but not window class.I am using window class in my code.so in modal dialog view image should be move with mouse.but if we make setmodal(true),we are unable to performing that.so i changed that to setmodal(false).now i can able to move the image but parent screens are not grayed out.i want to make background as grey color.kindly advise me.

Comment: @user3154688 provide some code to work with please. Also which window class are you using which has a setmodal method?